# bootstrap 4, .carousel-caption .bg-secondary .makeTransparent not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following html partial:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="/assets/_common/img/military-ship.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption  bg-secondary makeTransparent">
            <h3>Titlw</h3>
            <p>some test </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="/MH_Public_Contact/contact" role="button">Send Inquiry Now!</a></p>

        </div>
         ...[snip]...
```

There is TEXT and then a background of a grey box and then an image.  I want the grey box to be 50% transparent. In my CSS I have the following:

```
.carousel-caption .bg-secondary .shit
{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```

But for some reason it is completely opaque and no transparency.  Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: please provide snippet that shows your problem

Answer (score 1):

the `bg-secondary` class puts `background-color: #6c757d !important`... so just remove that class and the same color with your level of desired transparency on your `makeTransparent` class

working **snippet** below:

```css
.makeTransparent {
  background-color: rgba(108, 117, 125, 0.47)
}


/* Make the image fully responsive */

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
      <div class="carousel-caption  makeTransparent">
        <h3>Titlw</h3>
        <p>some test </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" role="button">Send Inquiry Now!</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
      <div class="carousel-caption  makeTransparent">
        <h3>Titlw</h3>
        <p>some test </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" role="button">Send Inquiry Now!</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York">
      <div class="carousel-caption  makeTransparent">
        <h3>Titlw</h3>
        <p>some test </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" role="button">Send Inquiry Now!</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```